# Sync OpenERP with Postgresql?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, odoo

I did this query on database directly:

```
UPDATE product_template SET track_external_partners=True
WHERE name !~* 'BOX'
```

So after this query it updated that field with given conditions. And if I write query if track_external_partners=True, it will give me desired results.

But if I connect to openerp (connect to same database) and go into product_templates, nothing have changed here, it looks like that command didn't affect OpenERP for some reason?

Is there need to be some kind of sync everytime you do this kind of update?

Comment: did you do that in a transaction? If so, did you commit your changes? If not, that may be the mistake

Comment: Now I did with Begin;, Commit;, but nothing changed in OpenERP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was wrong.
We have two databases with same name (on different ports). So I connected on old database which uses default port (5432), but our new database uses port 5433, so I needed to specify port like this:

```
psql dbname -p 5433
```

And now everything is fine.

Comment: cool, glad it was simple to fix :) can you mark it as answered?